# Is it possible to setup project level rule setup (opencover) in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

I have started using Sonar recently and one thing I noticed is that the opencover/fxcop rules applies to all the project running in Sonar server. I would like to know is it possible to apply one set of rules for a given project and another set of rules different project? There are couple of reasons for my question;

1. The same sonar server will be used by different groups and some are internal facing projects, where we are little linent on the rules when it comes to internal facing product. On the other hand, the common modules and customer facing, we want to follow strict rule set. One option is to run two different set of servers but want to know if there is an alternatives.
2. I totally agree to the fact, we should have same code quality
   standards for both internal and external facing but as we bring new
   product on board, those who have never done code quality standard gets initimidated with all the low score and we want to bring them on board with bare minimum and increase the rule check as group used to the sonar result.
3. Initially I thought, I could triage those errors on the project
   level and then it will not be applied in the future runs, but it
   seems, the triage applied only for that run so it will not help
   either.

   Any suggestions or comments on this appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar obviously provides the ability to define several different quality profiles (= rule sets) and to apply a specific profile to a specific project.

You'll find all the information in the documentation about quality profiles: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles

Comment: Side note, is there any industry standard number for Complexity/RCI?